# Why do we liquefy when we also solidify (but not soledefy)?

Tags: orthography

I always misspell liquefy and it drives me nuts.

**Solid**s will (or, I suppose, have) **solid**ify but **liquid**s apparently miss out on the chance to **liquid**ify. Instead they have to **liqu**efy I'm sure this is a simple English rule that I have forgotten from elementary school but I can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think this is explained by any English rule. It's just based on etymology.

The spelling *liquify* actually exists as a variant.

In terms of etymology, the Latin source of *liquefy* is *liquefacio,* which is supposed to have been derived from compounding the verb *liqueo* with *facio.* A  similarly formed (now obsolete in English) word is *calefy,* where the first part comes from the Latin verb *caleo.* *Putrefy* may also be analogous.

In contrast, the Latin ancestor of *solid,* the adjective *solidus,* has no corresponding verb *"soleo" or *"solideo" (an unrelated verb *soleo* "to be accustomed" exists). And the formation of the verb based on the adjective is supposed to have occurred in French, not in Latin: French *solide* + the French suffix *-(i)fier* made *[solidifier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/solidifier).*

Comment: Okay, wow. I've always spelled it with an *i* and never known (or realized or recalled) that it is not only also spelled with an *e* but that the *e* version is its primary spelling. In thinking about it, I must have known of the *e* version—but simply translated it in my head back into the *i* version I personally use. I just looked it up in all of my regular dictionaries—and this is indeed correct.

Comment: And I'd never known that there was any rationale behind this at all! I thought it was just another illustration of English spelling being neither phonetic nor logical.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'd always spelled it with an 'i' as well. So I ran an [Ngram analysis](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Liquefy%2C+liquify&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLiquefy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliquify%3B%2Cc0) on the two spellings and, guess what, "liquify" is far more common except for a little blip from about 1890 to about 1918 when they were just about equal. I think we're on the winning side.

Comment: @BoldBen: By default, the Google Ngram Viewer is sensitive to capitalization. If you compare "liquify" to "liquefy" (or do a [case-insensitive comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liquefy%2Cliquify&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cliquefy%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bliquefy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLiquefy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cliquify%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bliquify%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLiquify%3B%2Cc0)), the "e" spelling comes out ahead.

Comment: @sumelic Well done, I hadn't noticed the default capitalisation!

Comment: @JasonBassford "The e version is its primary spelling"... not primary according to Google Trends, which shows "liquify" outranking "liquefy" in all countries except Hong Kong, India, and Italy for the past 12 months. If this is an accurate reflection of real world usage, it seems "liquify" is fast on it's way to becoming the preferred spelling globally. Plus, Adobe chose "Liquify" for the name of their image distortion filter in Photoshop, so add 0.0001% credibility! (Anybody, add a comment if your localization differs.)